# Request: un-synonym-ize "clothing" and "footwear" tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

I just tagged a new question ["footwear" and was surprised to then find it with the clothing tag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/clothing/synonyms).
[That Q is not about clothing, it is about shoes for a hike.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/74072/32134)

A quick search reveals we have [100+ questions tagged clothing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing) but <s>[at least 45 of them have to do with footwear.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bclothing%5Dshoes)</s> (see edit below)

I propose to de-synonym-ize the "footwear" from the "clothing" tag. This needs a moderator to intervene.

**Edit:**
It has been pointed out in comments that my above quoted search yielding 45 "questions" actually counts **questions and answers**. Counting questions only, [there are 10 questions with the word "shoes"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bclothing%5D%20shoes%20is%3Aquestion) - and some of them also related to clothing as well as footwear.
I uphold my proposal as I still find it useful but given the drastic change in numbers I have decided to delete my poll answer (which stood at +15 vs -0) and replace it with a fresh one, given that many users' support was based upon these wrong numbers.
Apologies!

Comment: @IlmariKaronen well spotted, my mistake! What do you suggest in this case, does this invalidate my suggestion / the poll?

Comment: Dunno... also, sorry for deleting my previous comment; I got confused because I noticed some questions ([like this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/what-kind-of-clothes-and-footwear-are-ideal-to-visit-egypt)) in my search results that already *had* the [tag:footwear] tag, and thought they had already been split. But I guess those questions were posted *before* the synonym was created, and never edited since.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen your previous comment was very true. I have edited my question to correct this and deleted my poll answer replaced with a new one given that the previous one was based on incorrect numbers. The confusion described in your last comment likely is since the tags are synonyms but have not been merged - but I don't know the subtleties of that either. Since the suggested operation needs moderator intervention anyway, they should be able to find a wise decision. That is unless someone else comes up with a good suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has now been done: [clothing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing) and [footwear](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/footwear) are no longer synonyms.

Answer (score 11):

Poll answer:
Please vote up this answer if you agree with the proposal as made in my meta question and downvote if you disagree.

For a discussion please post another answer.

Please note that this is a new post given the edit made to my question.

Comment: +1; 10 is not a trivial number; that is more questions than [tag:pek], the second-busiest airport in the world, or [tag:medical-tourism], which was estimated at 60 billion USD in 2015, or [tag:shinkansen], arguably the most famous train system in the world, or [tag:olympics], which start in a week.

Comment: Its usually better to have 2 separate answers, one for agree, one for disagree, both upvote, and to state downvotes do not count. Reasoning is drive by voters like myself who only lurk and don't even have enough rep to downvote, skewing the vote positive.

Comment: It's usually better not to have poll answers at all - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279262/what-should-we-do-with-sets-of-answers-that-are-actually-polling-options/279267#279267

Comment: @Insane I did not consider that, thanks for pointing out. Given the comment by @ TimMalone I will abstain from poll answers in the future, so this should no longer be a problem. I do invite you to participate more on travel SE so you'd have a chance to downvote my posts :)

Comment: @TimMalone good point I was not aware of, I will abstain from poll answers in the future! Thanks

Comment: @mts I wish I knew more about travel :P

Comment: @Insane you can [ask](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about it :)

Comment: @Insane I don't have enough rep to downvote, that's why two answers are preferred.

Comment: Just for thoroughness and full disclosure, I have taken the negative point of view, so that those who agree with that can vote it or comment on it. Also, as I cannot upvote my own answer, I have down-voted this one. so, as of this evening, it's 12 for and 5 against

Answer (score 5):

I actually disagree with this for a couple reasons.

This stack exchange is about travel. Clothing is secondary to travel. For a large percentage of the questions, the question is about clothing to be used during some event while at the location gotten to by traveling, not used *during the travel itself.*

Shoes *are* articles of clothing. This leads us to the "what's next" line of reasoning. Hats? Winter vs Summer?

If I wanted to find out what gear would be recommended for hiking the Appalachian Trail, I would first be inclined to go to The Great Outdoors or to look for an exchange specifically about hiking. If I wanted to ask questions *about* the Appalachian Trail, I'd come here.

I see nothing wrong with shoes being a synonym of clothing, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: I travel on foot.

Comment: I'm aware... you are the best one among the regulars to comment on this topic, so? What are your thoughts?

Comment: To me, tags are fractal like. When the site is small there's less details so we see it "zoomed out" and it's fine to glom related tags together because there's few questions that distinguish them at a finer grain. But after a few years you "zoom in" to the fractal, and see more detail. There's a finer grain of topics and it makes sense to split tags into finer distinctions. So I think including footwear with clothing made good sense before and separating them makes good sense now.